# PPI diagonal resolution

Tags: diagonal, ppi

Can someone explain me clearly, why do we, when we count PPI (diagonal resolution/diagonal length) say that it is diagonal resolution? There are no diagonal pixels, it's just a length measured in pixels, but there aren't sqrt(pixel_width^2+pixel_height^2) pixels on the diagonal, no?

Answer (score 1):

Because pixels aren't necessarily square or evenly spaced. Suppose you have a block, 10 pixels wide by 10 pixels high. This block is also 1 inch wide by 1 inch high. Then:

```
PPI = sqrt(200) / sqrt(2) = 10 pixels per inch.
```

You could just have well measured along a horizontal or vertical line in the case of evenly spaced square pixels, and arrived at the same result.

But suppose you have a block, 1 inch wide by 1 inch high. But this time, it's 10 pixels wide by *5 pixels* high. Perhaps because the pixels are rectangular, or more spaced out vertically. If you measured horizontally, you'd get 10 PPI, and if you measure vertically you'd get 5 PPI. So we measure diagonally to be fair to unevenly distributed/non-square pixels. The actually PPI measured diagonally is about 7.9 PPI.